# Object passing in chromium extension

Tags: google-chrome, message

My extension creates an object in the background page and stores all
the configuration variables in that object. The object is common for
all content scripts and hence the background page sends it to the
content scripts after a connection request is received:

> // In background.html
>   timObject = {
>           property1 : "Hello",
>           property2 : "MmmMMm",
>           property3 : ["mmm", 2, 3, 6, "kkk"],
>           method1 : function(){alert("Method had been called" +
>   this.property1)}
>   };
>
> chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
>     console.assert(port.name == "forTimObject");
>     port.postMessage({object:timObject});
>   });
>
> // Now in content script:
>   var extensionObject = null;
>   var port = chrome.extension.connect({name: "forTimObject"});
>   port.onMessage.addListener( function(msg) {
>     if (msg.object != null)
>       extensionObject = msg.object;
>     else
>       alert("Object is null");
>   } );
>
> alert(extensionObject.property1);          // This is ok, alert box is displayed with the right contents
>   alert(extensionObject.method1)             //Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'method1'

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

[Google Chrome Message Passing mechanism](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/messaging.html) works serializing data to JSON:

> Communication between extensions and their content scripts works by using message passing [...] A message can contain any valid JSON object (null, boolean, number, string, array, or object).

If an object is sent using message passing, it will be convert to JSON. So, at the time of the "stringify][2](http://www.json.org/js.html)ing the method "method1" is lost as it cannot be transformed into a valid JSON expression. Unfortunately, it fails silently and it is confusing as the rest of the properties of the object are correctly serialized.